# What is the purpose of snapshot in Aeron Cluster?

Tags: aeron

I started learning about Raft as well as Aeron Cluster lately. One thing I come across is Aeron has the notion of taking snapshot to save the state of the machine. According to Raft, all the followers should have the same state as the leader. In that case, what's the purpose of snapshot? I thought with Raft, there shouldn't be any need to replay any log?

Answer (score 3):

A snapshot allows for fast recovery on restart. Without a snapshot the log would have to be replayed from the beginning of time to reach the same state. With a snapshot approach, the latest snapshot can be load and any log after this replayed to reach the same state.

Comment: Let's say we have scenario:

1 Leader, 4 Followers.. all working as expected. Leader died and election process worked as expected and one of the follower become leader. May be I'm wrong but from what I read so far, Raft protocol doesn't deal with restart (or in this case, the previous leader comes back to life). Is the restart deal with this situation? Or are we referring to "bigger" things like restart of the whole cluster, etc?

Comment: If we are talking about restarting the failed leader node (which hopefully can come back as a follower), won't that node should start processing from when it died? Why from the beginning of time?

Comment: You need to get the state machine back to the same state on restart of a node or whole cluster. In either case, a snapshot accelerates the restart process.